# ERROR PROMPT: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetCurrentEmployeeName()
{
    return db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(
        c => c.NTUserName == CurrentUsername()
    ).Last_First;
}
```

There's no NULL data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default of a reference type is `null`, so if there is no matching record the `SingleOrDefault` method returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, anything could be null in the above statement and you would get the above error.

```
db
Employees
c.NTUserName
```

You will have to debug through your code and find it out for yourself.